# Machine learning clustering algorithms: k-means and Gaussian mixtures

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

Suppose we clustered a set of N data points using two different clustering algorithms: k-means and Gaussian mixtures. In both cases we obtained 5 clusters and in both cases the centers of the clusters are exactly the same. Can 3 points that are assigned to different clusters in the kmeans solution be assigned to the same cluster in the Gaussian mixture solution? If no, explain. If so, sketch an example or explain in 1-2 sentences.

Comment: Of course, they can produce the same cluster assignments, depending on the data and initial conditions.

Comment: This might do better on the Computer Science stack

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belong to another stack exchange site: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BenKnoble, if you suggest another site, please make sure to explain to the poster that they should not post the same question on multiple SE sites: it violates site rules, and will just get them in trouble.  (Separately: this question is not at all suitable for CS.SE, due to the policies regarding problem dumps.)

Comment: @Joce, see above -- if you suggest another site, please make sure to explain to the poster that they should not post the same question on multiple SE sites: it violates site rules, and will just get them in trouble.

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50632/755

Comment: @D.W. thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of Machine Learning theory, Gaussian Mixture Model(GMM) and K-Means differ in the fundamental setting that K-Means is a Hard Clustering Algorithm, while GMM is a Soft Clustering Algorithm. K-Means will assign every point to a cluster whereas GMM will give you a probability distribution as to what is the probability of the point to belong in each of the 5 clusters. Furthermore, this also depends on the kind of parameters are you using for GMM. It could be possible for GMM to produce clusters somewhat similar to K-Means if you use a constant variance.

Now, I am not sure about this because you need to provide more information on how you are picking Hard Clusters from GMM and how are you calculating the cluster centers. If you are just making a hard assignment from GMM based on the cluster which has the maximum probability, then it could be possible that they get assigned to the same clusters. In my opinion this will be possible only if the data points are easily separable and your GMM is assuming constant variance.

As far as the cluster centers go, it depends on the way you are calculating them. If you are using the mean vectors obtained from GMM, then it is very very unlikely that K-Means and GMM will give you same cluster centers. On the other hand if you are first generating Hard clusters like mentioned above and then calculating the centers yourself, then it could be possible that they have the same centers when the hard clustering for all your points is the same in both K-Means and GMM.

I think you should provide more information about the way you are doing this, so that the community members can better help you. Also you should also identify your use case well and decide whether you need Hard or Soft Clustering. Choose GMM only if you desire soft clustering and/or you have a prior belief that your data points have been generated from Gaussian Distributions for each cluster.